# <dl> not allowing display:inline-block like <div> allows for

Tags: css

Good day, I have one single `<dl>` with multiple `<dt>` and `<dd>`.

What I'm hoping for, is through CSS (2 or 3), allow for one `<dt>` and it's child `<dd>` to be on a left column, the other one on a right column through a CSS class.

My current HTML:

```
<dl>
<dt class="LeftList"><a href="">DT Name</a></dt>
<dd>DD Info 1</dd>
<dd>DD Info 2</dd>
<dt class="RightList"><a href="">DT Name</a></dt>
<dd>DD Info 1</dd>
<dd>DD Info 2</dd>
</dl>
```

My current CSS:

```
.LeftList{
float:left;
margin-left:1.333em;
display:inline-block}

.RightList{
float:left;
margin-left:13em;
display:inline-block}
```

Comment: I would like each DT Name to line up (left and right) based on the margin given. Essentially, allow me to write up two columns.

Comment: see my edit with the fiddle

Comment: No, sorry. Your fiddle puts the 2nd DT underneath and to the right of the first. I would only like the 2nd DT to the right, not under.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

float elements are automatically displayed as a block elements, thus your inline is being ignored. Can you supply a picture of what you are trying to get?

I am just guessing that you are trying to get something like this:
For now I just changed your CSS a bit, as can be seen from the fiddle

```
.RightList{
margin-left:13em;
display:block}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nx7zws31/2/

please share with us a bit more information, abut your vision.

Comment: I see my edit. Asking for a picture or some indication of what you want to get

Comment: I have been able to get like you have, but see how the 2nd DT is underneath the first? I would like them to line up horizontally.

Comment: OK now I understand what you want :) Why not a table?

Comment: Boss keeps saying they prefer table-less web pages. Table was my first idea too haha. :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nx7zws31/2/ I based this on the following example http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/definition/

Comment: You are welcome. I removed some of the unneeded CSS and uploaded a new fiddle

Comment: Hmm another question. When I put in a 3rd DT it stays on the same line rather then going to the next line. Any ideas?

Comment: But then it's just one line again. I was hoping to just have 2 columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61125/discussion-between-quantico-and-ariestiger).